# CKEditor adds extra <p> tag

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

CKEditor inserts extra `<p>` tags when users enter a newline.

How do I disable this automatic paragraph tag?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify these settings to CKeditor.

```
// The writing rules for the <p> tag.
writer.setRules( 'p', {
// Inserts a line break after the <p> opening tag.
        breakAfterOpen : true,
}
```

This can either be set programmatically, via JS or I believe you should be able to add it directly via the UI, if you visit the Ckeditor settings page, there should be a box where you can enter ckeditor settings.

For more info see ckeditor docs: https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Output_Formatting

Answer (score 0):

Edit the Text format your users use and disable the option that turns new lines into paragraphs or breaks.

You can find the Text formats under `Configuration >  Content authoring > Text formats and editors`.

When you edit the one your users are using you will see that option enabled, you have to **disable it**:

[image: CKeditor options Text formats]